# Python Logger logging things twice to console

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to put together a logger using Python. I'm working in 2.6 so I can't use the new dictionary style method and instead am going with the good old fashioned config file. The problem is, stuff outputs twice to the console and I can't understand why. Here's my test script:

```
import logging
import logging.config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.config.fileConfig("newSlogger.conf")
    slogger = logging.getLogger("sloggerMain")

    slogger.debug("dbg msg")
    slogger.info("herp derp dominae")
```

Here's my config file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,sloggerMain,sloggerSecondary

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,infoFileHandler,debugFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter,infoFileFormatter,debugFileFormatter

[logger_root]
handlers=consoleHandler
level=NOTSET

[logger_sloggerMain]
handlers=consoleHandler,infoFileHandler,debugFileHandler
level=DEBUG
qualname=sloggerMain

[logger_sloggerSecondary]
handlers=consoleHandler,infoFileHandler,debugFileHandler
level=DEBUG
qualname=sloggerSecondary

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
format=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_infoFileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=infoFileFormatter
args=("testlog.log", "w")

[handler_debugFileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=debugFileFormatter
args=("testlogdbg.log", "w")

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(name)s: %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_infoFileFormatter]
format=%(name)s: %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_debugFileFormatter]
format=%(name)s: %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_syslogFormatter]
format=%(name)s: %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Change your non-root loggers to set `propagate` to 0, to prevent messages from being propagated up to the root logger:

```
[logger_sloggerMain]
handlers=consoleHandler,infoFileHandler,debugFileHandler
level=DEBUG
qualname=sloggerMain
propagate=0
```

The `logging` module's [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#loggers) say:

> Child loggers propagate messages up to
>   the handlers associated with their
>   ancestor loggers. Because of this, it
>   is unnecessary to define and configure
>   handlers for all the loggers an
>   application uses. It is sufficient to
>   configure handlers for a top-level
>   logger and create child loggers as
>   needed.

The `sloggerMain` logger is a child of the `root` logger. By default, messages emitted to that logger are also propagated upward.

You can also simply disable root logging to fix the problem:

```
[logger_root]
handlers=
```