# Logging messages appear twice in console Python

Tags: python, logging, jython

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566327/python-logger-logging-things-twice-to-console) answer to a seemingly similar issue, however (since I'm novice into Python) I am not sure how to implement this solution in my code (if it's the same issue after all).

In my code I have the following section:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    filename='C:\\Tests\\TRACE.log',
                    filemode='a')
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
consoleFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(consoleFormatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
localLog = logging.getLogger('text')
```

The funny thing is that it used to work fine but at some moment it started writing these duplicate messages to console.

Could someone give me a direction here please?

Comment: Although this is an old post, please add the output to the OP.  Otherwise it's hard to discern what is the specific problem and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that I have figured out the source of this problem.

The thing is that I used to get logger at module level. It looked pretty logical but there is a pitfall – Python logging module respects all created logger before you load the configuration from a file. So basically, when I was importing a module(which uses gets logger internally) to a main code(where I was calling for a logger as well) it resulted in streaming the logger data twice.

The possible solutions to this problem are:

1. Do not get logger at the module level
2. Set `disable_existing_loggers` to **False**. *Added since Python 2.7*

Answer (score 6):

Typically duplicate log statements occur because there are two separate handlers attached that are directing your log statements to the same place. There are a couple of things worth trying to get to the root of the problem:

1. Comment out the call to logging.basicConfig - if this eliminates the duplicate log statements then this means it is likely that you don't need to manually configure the second log handler.
2. If you are using an IDE, it may be worth putting a breakpoint onto a log statement, and stepping in using the debugger so you can introspect the state of pythons log setup to get a clearer picture of what different handlers are attached.

To make your logging easier to manage, it may be worth looking to move the configuration out of the code and into a configuration file - the Python document on [logging configuration](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) is a great place to start.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer but how can I comment out all the `loggingBasicConfig`? It includes mandatory settings as path, format and filemode...

Comment: From reading the question, it appears the problem is that you are getting duplicate log messages in the console, and that the file logging is not the problem. My suspicion is that the basicConfig is setting up a console log handler, and then you are setting up a second console log handler. Would highly recommend moving the logging configuration to a configuration file where you can be more explicit about the specific setup.

Comment: One thing worth pointing out is that logging to file, console or any other destination isn't mandatory - logging is simply a way of directing messages to a useful place to view or store them, and there are many different places you may want to send them (file and console being two very common options). Would highly recommend working through the [advanced logging tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial) in the python documentation to get a solid introduction into how logging works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation with my logger configuration, the fix that i used was:

```
class Logger:

@staticmethod
def setup(name, file_name):

    log_file = <path to save the file>
    log_file_max_size = 1024 * 1024 * 20  # megabytes
    log_num_backups = 3
    log_format = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(filename)s(%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s) >> %(message)s"
    log_filemode = "w"  # w: overwrite; a: append
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, format=log_format, filemode=log_filemode, level=logging.DEBUG)
    rotate_file = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
        log_file, maxBytes=log_file_max_size, backupCount=log_num_backups
    )
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    # Console output line.
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
    console_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    logger.handlers = rotate_file, console_handler

    return logger
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some solution if you want to create logger in separate file. I used information from @(Joshua Briceño Z) answer, however I had some issues with saving logs to a file.

Basically I dropped the basicConfig, and to console_handler I added propagate=0 to skip printing twice.

Here I have two files:

1. **config.py** - where is a Logger Class that setups the logger;
2. **program.py** - where I call a Logger Class from config and tell to which file save the logs.

**config.py**:

```
import logging

class Logger:
    """
    Sets the logger.

    Attributes:
    :file_name: set a filename in which logs will be saved.
    :name: set the name of specific logger.

    :return: function
    """

    @staticmethod
    def setup(name: str, file_name: str):
        log_file = file_name
        log_format = "%(asctime)s - %(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s"
        log_level = logging.INFO
  
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)

        # File output line
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        # Console output line
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setLevel(log_level)
        log_formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
        console_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
        logger.addHandler(console_handler)
        logger.propagate = 0

        return logger
```

**program.py**

```
import config
logger_1 = config.Logger.setup(name='program', file_name='program.log')
```

*NOTE:* Tested on python 3.8.10.